# Converting rows into column and combining two database table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this database table.

```
dbo.tblSites

| Site_Code | Site Name |
     A         Aaaaaa
     B         Bbbbbb
     C         Cccccc
     D         Dddddd
```

And this is the other table

```
 dbo.Server
| Site_Code | ServerName | Status |         Timestamp        | 
      A          QQQ        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:00.000
      A          QQQ        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:03.000
      A          QQQ      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      A          WWW      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:02.000
      A          WWW      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      A          WWW        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:06.000
      A          EEE        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      A          EEE        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:07.000
      A          EEE      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:08.000
      B          QQQ        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:00.000
      B          QQQ        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:03.000
      B          QQQ      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      B          WWW      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:02.000
      B          WWW      Critical   01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      B          WWW        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:06.000
      B          EEE        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:05.000
      B          EEE        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:07.000
      B          EEE        OK       01/02/2016 10:00:08.000
```

I need to get all the sitecodes and put it as a Column
I also need to put under the column the "LATEST" status of the server

```
| ServerName | SiteCode-A | SiteCode-B |   SiteCode-C   |   SiteCode-D   |
     QQQ        Critical     Critical     No Data Found    No Data Found
     WWW          OK            OK        No Data Found    No Data Found
     EEE        Critical        OK        No Data Found    No Data Found
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [dynamic crosstab](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ba279/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
    ServerName' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Site_Code = ''' + Site_Code + '''THEN Status END), ''No Data Found'') AS '  + QUOTENAME('SiteCode-'+Site_Code) + CHAR(10)
FROM tblSites
ORDER BY Site_Code

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM (
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Site_Code, ServerName ORDER BY Timestamp DESC)
    FROM [Server]
) t
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY ServerName
ORDER BY ServerName'

PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Dynamic Crosstab, is the single quotation mark is relevant if I try putting it in SQL Server?

Comment: There is also an error when I write it down on SQL Server saying "Cannot assign a default value to a local variable." and another is "Must declare the scalar variable "@sql"."

Comment: I got it. Thank you @Felix. I already configure the codes. Thanks alot

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: @Elphrian: if you log on here again, please consider accepting this answer. To do so, click on the green tick mark to the left of the answer, so mark it as correct.